# Issues with convert_dtypes() from pandas

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion

I'm trying to extract data from an .xlsx file that is a bit of a mess. I've managed to extract the data I need, and write it to an excel file output, but I'd very much like to convert the numbers to floats 'on the fly' so that I can reuse my script for other instances of similar files.

This is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

data_folder = Path("Data/")
file = data_folder / "Binder1.pdf.xlsx"

data = pd.read_excel(file, header=None, index_col=None)

Names = list(data.loc[data[0] == 'Injection Name:'] [2])
headers = data[data[1].astype(str).str.contains("Peak")].dropna(axis=1, how='all').
                                                          iloc[0, :].str.replace(r'\n', ' ')

subset = data[data[1].astype(str).str.contains("Compound")]
my_results = subset.dropna(axis=1, how='all')
my_results.index = Names
my_results.columns = headers

result = pd.DataFrame

for col in my_results:
    str_results = my_results[col].astype(str).
            str.replace('not valid', 'NotValid').str.replace('n.a.', '0').str.replace(r'\n', ' ')
    str_final = str_results.str.split(' ').explode()
    if not result.empty:
        str_final_x = str_final.convert_dtypes()
        result = pd.concat([result, str_final], axis=1, ignore_index=False)
    else:
        result = str_final.to_frame()

final = result[result['Peak Name'].astype(str).str.contains("Compound_X")]
final.to_excel("Output.xlsx")
```

I was hoping .convert_dtypes() would automatically recognize the datatype of the column, but everything comes out as text. To further complicate matters, the row values are occasionally written as 'n.a.', hence the replace with 0 below. Is there a way to do this that doesn't involve specifying each column type individually?

The image below shows the datastructure after I've extracted all my data.

[Data structure after extraction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGwDg.png)

Comment: Have you tried using .astype(float) ?

Comment: @bgmello, no, I hadn't, thank you. I have now though, and I cannot get it to work either, since the datatypes in the columns are a mix of strings and numbers. I ended up with 

`str_final.astype(float, errors='ignore' )`

which changes nothing unfortunately :(

Comment: You can't change some of the values in a column to float while leaving others as strings, they have to be homogeneous. Here you can see the documentation of pandas https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/basics.html. "When working with heterogeneous data, the dtype of the resulting ndarray will be chosen to accommodate all of the data involved. For example, if strings are involved, the result will be of object dtype. If there are only floats and integers, the resulting array will be of float dtype."

Comment: @bgmello Sorry, had some logon problems - it did work! But there was a typo in my script that I hadn't noticed ... so when I substituted the str_final with str_final_x in the concat statement, my numbers were converted to floats. Final script became:

`str_final_x = str_final.astype(float, errors='ignore')
 result = pd.concat([result, str_final], axis=1, ignore_index=False)`

which resulted in 5 out of 8 columns being correctly turned into float64 values.

Thanks!

Comment: `result = pd.concat([result, str_final.astype(float, errors='ignore')], axis=1, ignore_index=False)`

of course.